# Flutter: Do you have an idea on how to create a scrollable stack with few positioned widgets and mostly empty space?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, scrollview

for a project, I need to create a ScrollView that takes a list of Positioned-widgets and outputs a scrollview with a fixed height, which outputs a stack with only a few widgets positioned on it.

I can easily create it using SingleChildScrollView, but then the children are not dynamically rendered and when having a very long ScrollView with many children, the app becomes too slow.

Here is the example code:

```
class DisplayListview extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> getScrollviewWidgets() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    widgets.add(
      Container(
        width: 1000,
        height: 100000,
      ),
    );
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
      Widget widget = Positioned(
        left: 100,
        top: 100 + (100 * i).toDouble(),
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
      widgets.add(widget);
    }
    return widgets;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        children: getScrollviewWidgets(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Positioned-widgets can overlap in the scrollDirection, thus a list is not an option. They can also be positioned anywhere in the stack and have various sizes.

Do you have an idea how to create a widget that dynamically creates the Positioned-widgets when they should become visible?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Visibility class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)

The visible property controls whether the child is included in the subtree or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer myself:
I can use SliverStack inside a CustomScrollView from the sliver_tools package ([sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools)).

But thank you anyway Jaime!